# Using RT kernel with Nvidia on Ubuntu Mate

Tags: nvidia, sound, mate, realtime

I'm trying to use the linux-rt kernel in Ubuntu Mate. It installs and runs fine. The rub is, I need to retain Nvidia mode, as the laptop's hdmi output runs solely through the external card.

With the stock kernel, I can choose the graphics mode as expected (really good work, that, out of the box! Thank you!), however, when booted into the rt kernel, I can not.

I seem to remember years ago, this was a strict no-go as the drivers wouldn't compile. But that was like 5 years ago. I can't imagine it is still the case, is it? I'm not finding much about this searching around. I can't believe I'm the only one with this problem...

RT kernels aren't as necessary as they used to be, but Ardour seems to think it is...

Thank you for any insights.
Tom

Comment: Sorry. You are correct. Not ARM. Intel processor and GTX graphics. Kernels are latest in repo, which is 5.4.

Comment: Sorry. You are correct. Not ARM. Intel processor and GTX 1650 graphics. Kernels are latest in repo, which is 5.4. I wasn't that specific, I suppose, because I'm looking for a more broad answer at first. Either it's possible to build the nvidia drivers against the RT kernels or it isn't. (And I'm beginning to suspect it isn't) Once that's established, we can get into the weeds as necessary. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1

Comment: Both generic and lowlatency kernels are 5.4.0-42